# Predictions of a multiclass problem with Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a multiclass problem, that contains twelve classes (Class `0`, `1`, `2`, ..., `11`). My `x_train` has shape `(31187, 36)` and `y_train` has shape `(31187,)`.

Here is an example of my `y_train` array which contain the classes of each sample of my train dataset:

```
y_train
Out[25]: array([ 6,  8,  1, ..., 11,  0,  4], dtype=int64)
```

I have used `LabelBinarizer()` as follows to encode my output into a one-hot-encode format:

```
label_bin = LabelBinarizer()
unique_classes = np.unique(y_train)
label_bin.fit_transform(unique_classes)
```

And got this output from it:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I then proceed to train my classifier:

```
y_train_one_hot = label_bin.transform(y_train)
classifier_MLP = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(2*x_train.shape[1],
                                                   4*y_train_one_hot.shape[1],
                                                   2*y_train_one_hot.shape[1]),
                               max_iter=500,
                               random_state=42)
classifier_MLP.fit(x_train, y_train_one_hot)
```

Here is my question. When using the `predict` method, why some samples does not comes in the `LabelBinarizer` format (one-hot-encoded)?

For example, to following sample (sample  `8`) of my `x_test` dataset, yields this:

```
classifier_MLP.predict(x_test[8].reshape(1, -1))
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

But, according to the encode I have done, I was expecting to get this array instead?

```
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

If I check which class that is, using the `inverse_transform` method, I get class `0` as output:

```
label_bin.inverse_transform(classifier_MLP.predict(x_test[8].reshape(1, -1)))
array([0], dtype=int64)
```

This does not happens all the time, some samples (for example, sample `42`), does actually return what I expect:

```
classifier_MLP.predict(x_test[42].reshape(1, -1))
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Which is the class `0`:

```
label_bin.inverse_transform(classifier_MLP.predict(x_test[42].reshape(1, -1)))
array([0], dtype=int64)
```

What could be the cause of this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try supplying y directly to `LabelBinarizer().fit_transform()` or `.fit()`. It determines the unique classes itself, without you needing to use `np.unique(y)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think that's the issue. I have checked that already, and it does not change anything at all how the predictons are made.

Comment: I think `MLPClassifier` can work without `LabelBinarizer`. Would it help to train the classifier directly on y?

Comment: Yes, it does work, but the performance is subpar. That is the reason i was trying another approach using `LabelBinarizer`.

Comment: In my understanding, `LabelBinarizer` wouldn't improve `MLPClassifier` because the classifier already supports multiclass data. So if `MLPClassifier` was not exhibiting good performance, I think the issue may be related to the parameters used (tuning) or the data/features fed in. `MLPClassifier` will perform better if your input features are scaled, perhaps you're already doing this. If you fit the classifier with a lot of layers on a small sample of your data, you should easily overfit the sample and get a good train score. You could work back from there to see where things drop.